# How to fetch logged in user's friend's friend list in IOS 6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

In my application i'm getting logged in user's friend list by using FBFriendPickerViewController, if i select any one in that list i'm able to display his details like name, id, location etc. My question is that by using these details how can i get his(selected friend in FBFriendPickerViewController) friends list in my app?.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 NSArray *accounts = [accountStore
                                   accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];
              ACAccount *facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
              NSString *acessToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",facebookAccount.credential.oauthToken];
              NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"access_token": acessToken};
              NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends"];
              SLRequest *feedRequest = [SLRequest
                                        requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                        requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                        URL:feedURL
                                        parameters:parameters];
              feedRequest.account = facebookAccount;
              [feedRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData,
                                                       NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
               {
                   NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
               }];
          }
          else
          {
              // Handle Failure
          }
```